# Set Value method puts the value too fast

Tags: java, android, appium

The setValue method putting value in the field too fast and losing some chars during a process.
sendKeys method doesn't work correctly too.

[https://pp.userapi.com/c849532/v849532534/1d4fe6/BEVb5_C3O8E.jpg][]

Appium Server 1.13.0

```
package appiumtests2;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.URL;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class Stoloto {

    /*
     * static WebDriver driver;
     * AndroidDriver driver;
     */
    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Stoloto stoloto = new Stoloto();
            stoloto.openStoloto();

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void openStoloto() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel XL");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "HT6B70200690");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "ru.stoloto.mobile");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "ru.stoloto.mobile.ca.presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);
        System.out.println("Application Started...");
        MobileElement onBoardContinue = driver.findElement(By.id("ru.stoloto.mobile:id/confirm"));

        onBoardContinue.click();

        onBoardContinue.click();
        MobileElement onBoardLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("ru.stoloto.mobile:id/login"));
        onBoardLogin.click();
        MobileElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.id("ru.stoloto.mobile:id/user"));
        String login = "testtesttest@gmail.com";
        sleep(1000);
        loginField.setValue(login);
        MobileElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("ru.stoloto.mobile:id/passwordInputEdit"));
        String password = "qwertyqwerty";
        sleep(1000);
        passwordField.setValue(password);

        driver.hideKeyboard();

        MobileElement log_in = driver.findElement(By.id("ru.stoloto.mobile:id/buttonSubmit"));
        log_in.click();
        System.out.println("Test Completed");

    }

}
```

I need to find a way to set value with a little delay or the other way, which help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mobile:shell`](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/#mobile-shell) command for sending text to the device via [adb shell](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

```
Map<String, Object> argv = new HashMap<>();
argv.put("command", "input");
argv.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("text", "your_text_here"));
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", argv);
```

Alternatively you can consider using `elementSendText` function avaiable via [Appium SeeTest Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55281084)

```
driver.executeScript("seetest:client.elementSendText(\"NATIVE\", \"id=your_element_id\", \"0\", \"your_text_here\")");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `WebDriverWait` in order to set the value